# PySpark If condition function execution for Dataframes

Tags: dataframe, if-statement, pyspark

I have a scenario where I have one dataframe and 2 different functions that need to be applied on this dataframe depending on some filters.

What I am trying to do is apply 1 seperate function to a dataframe with one set or rows and apply
another function to the same dataframe with another set of rows

The functions are like this:

```
def date_time_preprocessing_xml(df: DataFrame):
    some_processing...
```

```
def date_time_preprocessing_log(df: DataFrame):
    some_processing...
```

Here is what I am trying to do. Filter the dataframe which has certain rows with "-" and the other with "/" and apply the processing accordingly

```
# check if this Date & Time row is a xml file entry
    if common_df.filter((f.col("Element") == "Date & Time") & (f.col("Value").contains("-"))):
        common_df = date_time_preprocessing_xml(common_df)  # for xml file input row
    else:
        common_df = date_time_preprocessing_log(common_df)  # for log file input row
```

But the problem is that only one functions is being called all the time and not the other

I also tried to do 2 seperate functions for same dataframes and then tried union them together
but I am not able to do it that way.

Also tried using the when, otherwise condition but this is applicable for only columns and my intention is to get the entire dataframe processed

Thanks and Regards

Comment: You need to create two separate dataframes through filter operations. df1 and df2, apply the respective functions and the union the result if that is what is your aim.

Comment: Can you share some data where you need to use this fucntion>?